# Given a list of n 4x4 matrices, how do I combine them such that they follow consecutively resulting in a 4nx4 matrix

Tags: r, matrix, merge

What I want to do is given a list [mat1, mat2, mat3, ..., matn] where each matrix is 4x4 create a large 4nx4 matrix:

mat1
mat2
mat3

I did this using a loop but my list is about 12000 matrices and it took forever... how could I do this in a more efficient way?

Comment: Hi there, please try to clarify your question by moving some of the text from the title into the body of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
do.call(rbind, list(mat1, mat2, mat3))
```

or

```
## Collect the matrices into a list
MATS <- lapply(paste0("mat", 1:n), function(x) get(x))

## rbind them all into one
do.call(rbind, MATS)
```

Answer (score 4):

The abind package is useful for this kind of thing as it will directly accept a list.  It's definitely worth knowing about for manipulating matrices and arrays.

```
library(abind)
mat <- matrix(1, ncol = 4, nrow = 4)
abind(list(mat, mat), along = 1)
```